# Serial port monitoring

Tags: raspbian, usb, serial

I'm trying to watch serial ports.

For that I need the serial port address, but... on the network people's says that address follow unix pattern, like this "/dev/ttyUSB0", but if I enter on raspbian terminal and type.

```
ls /dev/ttyUSB*
```

I recieve this mesage

```
ls: cannot access /dev/ttyUSB*: No such file or directory
```

I've already tried PySerial, but when i ran the script, the terminal return me an huge error saying what the serial port doesn't exist.

I need some help, I want get away of this problem faster possible.

Comment: That comes up for me sometimes so I searched. No clean way, but "dmsg | grep tty' seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name given to the serial port depends principally on how but also on what you have connected.

If you connect a 3.3V safe TTL serial link to the Pi's GPIO (pins 8/10) then the serial port is called /dev/ttyAMA0 or (rarely) /dev/ttyS0.  On Raspbian you should preferentially use the link /dev/serial0.

If you connect via a USB dongle plugged in to the Pi the serial port will normally be named /dev/ttyUSB0 for the first, /dev/ttyUSB1 for the second etc.  An exception is if the other end of the dongle is connected to an Arduino in which case the port is likely to be named /dev/ttyACM0.

Comment: I did it, I connected an Arduino in one USB port, and the /dev/ttyUSB0 appeared.

Comment: Its so confusing all these port names ...